# bash: ./loopy: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos

i have installed "Loopy" programme in Linux CentOS, but when try to run it said :

> `bash: ./loopy: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory`

How to set path for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [howtodoityourself.org](http://www.howtodoityourself.org/how-to-fix-libld-linux-so-2-bad-elf-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory.html),

> You need to install `glibc.1686`. Do it by:
>
> ```
> yum -y install glibc.i686
> ```
>
> **This will happen only on 64 bit systems**, the cause is the fact that 32 bit  libraries are missing from the system, so you can easily fix this issue by installing the 32 bit libraries on your system.

### EDIT:

For your

```
 ./loopy: error while loading shared libraries:
libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file
or directory
```

error, try `yum provides`:

```
yum provides libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3
```

It will answer you like this:

```
compat-libstdc++-296.i386                2.96-135               core
Matched from:
libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3
```

Then, do a

```
yum install compat-libstdc++-296
```

Comment: again one problem occur system said:   ./loopy: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory